# Groupby two columns pandas dataframe and shift().rolling()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to groupby two columns, 'Y' and 'A', then `shift().rolling()` for column 'ValueA'.
I tried this code but result is not correct.

Code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Y' : [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    'A' : ['b','c','a','c','a','c','b','c','a', 'a', 'b', 'b','c','a','a','b'],
    'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b','c','a','a','b','b','c','a','c','a','c','b','c'],
    'ValueA':[1,2,2,1,2,4,7,1,3,2,4,3,1,2,4,5],
    'ValueB':[3,2,4,3,1,2,4,5,1,2,2,1,2,4,7,1]
})
df['ValueX'] = df.groupby(['Y','A'])['ValueA'].shift().rolling(3, min_periods=3).sum()
```

Output for 'A' == a

```
    Y   A   B   ValueA  ValueB  ValueX
2   0   a   b   2       4       NaN
4   1   a   c   2       1       NaN
8   1   a   b   3       1       NaN
9   1   a   c   2       2       9.0
13  1   a   c   2       4       7.0
14  1   a   b   4       7       5.0
```

Expected Output

```
    Y   A   B   ValueA  ValueB  ValueX
2   0   a   b   2       4       NaN
4   1   a   c   2       1       NaN
8   1   a   b   3       1       NaN
9   1   a   c   2       2       NaN
13  1   a   c   2       4       7.0
14  1   a   b   4       7       7.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We need to to perform both `shift` and `rolling` operation per group**, but instead you are performing the `shift` operation per group then rolling operation for the entire column which is producing the incorrect output.

```
df['ValueX'] = df.groupby(['Y', 'A'])['ValueA']\
                 .apply(lambda v: v.shift().rolling(3).sum())
```

---

```
print(df)

    Y  A  B  ValueA  ValueB  ValueX
0   0  b  a       1       3     NaN
1   0  c  a       2       2     NaN
2   0  a  b       2       4     NaN
3   1  c  b       1       3     NaN
4   1  a  c       2       1     NaN
5   1  c  a       4       2     NaN
6   1  b  a       7       4     NaN
7   1  c  b       1       5     NaN
8   1  a  b       3       1     NaN
9   1  a  c       2       2     NaN
10  1  b  a       4       2     NaN
11  1  b  c       3       1     NaN
12  1  c  a       1       2     6.0
13  1  a  c       2       4     7.0
14  1  a  b       4       7     7.0
15  1  b  c       5       1    14.0
```

As a side note, you don't have to explicitly specify the `min_periods` optional argument, it will default to the window size if not specified.

Comment: Thanks! And if I have Datatime as index, how I can do the rolling average of Last n days? I tried to add '30D' in rolling but does not work, result is not correct.